# How can I change Board outline clearance in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

I changed a 6 layer PCB to 8 layer PCB by adding 2 plane layers in layer stack manager.

However, newly added plane layers have a thick clearance to board outline.
I cannot select the thick green line in the below image. Thickness is 1mm and there is no such rule in Rules (no 0.5mm rule or 1mm rule).

How can I modify these board outline clearence?
In the manufacturing tab in the rules, everything is 0.2mm not 1mm or 0.5mm
Thanks.

[image: Board outline]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the pullback in the "Layer Stack Manager" window.

Right click on one of the layers tab in your PCB view. Now, click on "*Layer Stack Manager*."

[image]

Select the plane layer you wish to modify and change the pullback distance in the input box:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Layer Stack Manager's Properties panel, with the relevant Plane layers selected, you can find an entry for Pullback Distance, which specifies how the copper for that plane layer should be pulled back from the board edge/outline.

The Altium on-line documentation for the [Layer Stack Manager](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/defining-layer-stack#!editing-the-layer-stack-properties) describes this. (Ctrl-F for `Pullback Distance`)